# Pivot Table Excel to Google Sheets add a Calculated value on a column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot-table

I'm trying to convert a Pivot Table from Excel to Google Sheets.

Data :
[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TkTV.png)

There is my Pivot Table :
[Pivot Table Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EArtQ.png)

I just want to do the same on Google Sheets, i've got this :
[Pivot Table GSheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mNQe.png)

As you can see, on the first picture, there is a column "YTD", it seems to be a calculated field but I don't know how to do the same on GSheets because if I add a calculated value, it doesn't add a column, but a row and that looks very bad and I absolutely need to have the same configuration in order to convert an existing macro Excel to Google Apps Script.

If you have a tips in order to solve my issue, it could be very nice !

Also I don't really know what formula I can write for YTD, I'm a young trainee so if you have an answer on that it could be very useful :)

Comment: Do you know how the field is calculated? Also, can you share an example of the google sheet with the data / dummy data?

Comment: I think I know, this field represents average result from first day of the year until today. 

You want me to share a Sheets with you or just screenshots ?

Comment: Share a Sheets Publicly with dummy data if needed. This way more people can see it and help you as well. You can do an update on the initial question adding it and adding more details if you have them.